# How to Set Wheelnav.js Spin Direction Always the Shorted Distance?

Tags: wheelnav.js

How can wheelnav.js be setup to rotate both clockwise and counterclockwise, whichever is closest? Whenever it goes from 0 to the highest number, it flips around the long way, as seen when you go from 0 to 5 on this demo page after turning on rotation:
http://pmg.softwaretailoring.net/

It needs to always rotate in the closest direction and never flip around the long way.

I am also open to a solution using wheelizate tabs, which uses Wheelnav to accomplish this: 
http://wtabs.softwaretailoring.net/

Thank you for your attention on this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by doing a Console.log(rotationAngle), and watching what the rotation value for each particular click. Then I found that I could take the numbers of the situations that went the wrong way, and subtract 360 from it to get it to rotate the opposite direction.

The patch involve adding this to Wheelnav.js line 411:

```
        if (rotationAngle == 288){
            rotationAngle = -72;
        }

        if (rotationAngle == 216){
            rotationAngle = -144;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the next line (line 422 of Wheelnav.js):

```
navItem.currentRotateAngle -= rotationAngle;
```

with the following conditional expression:

```
if (rotationAngle >= 180) {
  rotationAngle = 360 - rotationAngle;
  navItem.currentRotateAngle += rotationAngle;
} else if (Math.abs(rotationAngle) > 180) {
  rotationAngle = 360 + rotationAngle;
  navItem.currentRotateAngle -= rotationAngle;
} else {
  navItem.currentRotateAngle -= rotationAngle;
}
```